# Will TypeScript 2.0 support VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript2.0

I can't find any download for TypeScript 2.0 for VS 2013. And can't find any description about dropping support for VS 2013.

Comment: The release notes for TypesScript 2.0 RC say that you can download it for VS 2015. They don't mention VS 2013, so I guess you need VS 2015 for now. Maybe they'll backport it later.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/08/30/announcing-typescript-2-0-rc/

Comment: So I need an official description, whether they need more time to make 2013 version ready, or they have decided to drop support. Then I'll decide to wait, or ask my team members to upgrade, then I can use Angular 2 in our new project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears they have decided *not* to support TypeScript 2.0 in Visual Studio 2013 according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11214).

Answer (score 3):

[Dan Def](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6803697/dan-def) already answered to this question. From the above link, we get to know the below information.

[Mohamed Hegazy(mhegazy)](https://github.com/mhegazy) Commented as below, according to this    [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11214):

> Just to be clear, TypeScript 2.0 is **not** available as a plugin for
>   Visual Studio 2013. TypeScript **1.8** is the last version of TypeScript
>   to be shipped to **VS 2013**. As noted earlier, we have moved our active
>   development to the newer version of Visual Studio.
>
> TypeScript 2.0 is available for Visual Studio 2015 as a standalone
>   installer, and in-box for Visual Studio "15" Preview 5.

Hence, Posted in order to give quick clarity. Hope this helps.,

***Edit 1:***

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs): Note that **VS2015 Update 2 is not enough. You need VS2015 Update 3**, because it fixes some issues with *NPM*, plus it’s a prerequisite for `TypeScript 2.0`. Reference From [Stevensanderson Blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)